# How to calculate whether it's worth turning on a fan to bring warmer air to a heat pump hot water heater?

Tags: water-heater, ducts, home-automation, energy-efficiency, heat-pump

I have 4 new Rheem 50 gal heat pump hot water heaters being installed in the basement of my home/multiunit property that is a 4-unit building (one heater per apartment).

Generally speaking, the attic is warmer than the basement. It occurs to me that it might make sense to move some hot air from the attic to the basement in order to make the water heaters more efficient. I could put a temp sensor in the attic and a temp sensor in the basement and only turn on the fan when there is a certain delta between them. Sounds like a fun arduino project right?!

My question is - how do I determine when it's worth turning on the fan in a more robust way? For example, I should probably consider how much energy the fan consumes and compare that to the energy saved by providing warmer air to to heaters. This is where things get out of my pay grade. The air would likely be exhausted near the heaters, or I could investigated ducting directly to the intake.

For the sake of getting some numbers, let's start with the following:

- 4" duct at 30'
- A 30 watt inline fan
- The Rheem heater I'm using is the XE50T10H45U0 model
- 3.75 Unified Energy Factor
- I live in Maine
- Other factors?

Thanks for playing along!

Comment: It's going to be quite difficult to calculate this due to the number of variables that can't really be determined.  Another approach is to try it both ways and see if you can measure any change in the efficiency over time.

Comment: You might experience excessive dampness / condensation if you're bringing attic air into the basement...

Comment: An alternate approach would be to just run the duct, and then use a damper (only powered when moving) to switch whether the fans you are already running in the water heaters pull in attic air or basement air - But I think a single 4" duct is a bit undersized to feed 4 of them, particularly when it's 30 feet long. I don't own one (yet) but I do recall that they permit attaching (some) ducting to direct the cooled air and to get the hot air. I recall them having a condensate drain already, so they would pull out any dampness in the supplied air.

Comment: You know you're going to have to heat that room, right?  **A lot**.  Otherwise in the winter you'll have residents storing ice cream in that room...